# Html with Thunderbird

Tags: html, css

I have this code, it's a template that he adapted a bit. When I look in local as it is fine, when I send it with Thunderbird attached the html does not. You do not see the images that I have that I take them from dropbox, nor the styles.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tveOo.png)  -->This is in Local

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7HbA.png)  -->This is in Thunderbird

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- If you delete this meta tag, Half Life 3 will never be released. -->
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/email.css" />
    </head>
    <!------------------------------------
    ---- HEADER --------------------------
    ------------------------------------->
    <table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#FFFF00">
        <tr>
            <td class="header container">
                <div class="content">
                <table bgcolor="#FFFF00" class="">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="Imagen" style="width:200px; margin-left: 30px;"  /></td>
                        <td> <img src="Imagen2" style="width:200px;" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!------------------------------------
    ---- BODY ----------------------------
    ------------------------------------->
    <table class="body-wrap">
        <tr>
            <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <!-- content -->
                <div class="content">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h1>Motor honda</h1>
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><img src="foto3" style="width=250px;"  />
                                        </th>
                                        <th><img src="foto4"style="width=250px;" />
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tr>
                                </table>
                                <!-- A Real Hero (and a real human being) -->
                                <!-- /hero -->
                                <!-- Callout Panel -->
                                <p class="callout">
                                    Message2
                                </p><!-- /Callout Panel -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- COLUMN WRAP -->
                <div class="column-wrap">
                    <div class="column">
                        <table align="left">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="column">
                        <table align="left">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <!-- social & contact -->
                                    <table bgcolor="" class="social" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <table align="left" width="100%">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <h6 class="">Connect with Us:</h6>
                                                    <p class=""><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="soc-btn fb">Facebook</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="soc-btn tw">Twitter</a> </p>
                                                    <h6 class="">Contact Info:</h6>
                                                    <p><strong>Phone:</strong> <br/>
                                                    <p><strong>Web: </strong> <br/>
                                                    <strong> Email:</strong><a href="emailto:hseldon@trantor.com"></a></p>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table><!-- /social & contact -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div><!-- /COLUMN WRAP -->
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <table class="footer-wrap">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="container">
                    <!-- content -->
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table><!-- /FOOTER -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need to put the images and css on a server.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to files in the same folder as your html file. Since you are not sending whole folder, you can't have access to those files in Thunderbird. 
Try

```
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/pathToYourImage" style="width=250px;"  />
```

Instead of:

```
<img src="foto3" style="width=250px;"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your css file and image files into full URL paths. Most email softwares will allow you to upload images and other files directly to their servers, or if you have your own web server, you can store those files on there as well.